# Opera: why would I want to upgrade to version 10.0?

Tags: opera, opera-10

I noticed that Opera 10 has just been released. What is a 
compelling reason to upgrade?

I have no problems using v9.64 (it is fast enough, thank 
you) and Opera Software does not do a good job informing 
about the differences. As Opera 10 has been in beta for some 
time maybe some of you can share some experience using it.

The only thing I am missing is a way to have several lists 
of RSS feeds instead of one big list, e.g. one list for high-value podcasts with low 
traffic, one for lower-value podcasts and one for high traffic Stack Overflow updates.

Comment: Because the version number is higher. And we all know that a higher version number means it's cool. I wonder why they didn't turn it into Opera 5000. Yay Marketing.

Comment: Actually, the version number is not higher, it froze to 9.80 (at least for the user-agent) : http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/30/opera-10-user-agent/ :-)

Comment: The problem with skipping to Opera 5000 would be certain users assuming it could not be used until the year 5000 - wheras with opera 10, it's been tested for almost 2000 years, and so must be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you go to Opera.com, then to the "browser" section, you have the "features" page, which answers to what you are asking for : [the new features](http://www.opera.com/browser/features/).

Answer (score 4):

Consider this page http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/1000/
While 9.64 is a good browser its fork is going to end. Granted I'm biased... beta programs on a beta OS...

[Timeline](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Timeline_of_Opera_Releases.svg) mildly out of date, but to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 2):

> Opera Software does not do a good job
>   informing about the differences.

[**Opera Changelogs**](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/) for all platforms

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this (and other situations) in terms of why wouldn't you want to upgrade? Cost is not an issue. Does it add some feature that you don't want and can't turn off?

Newer versions usually have more features, or the existing features have been improved. As others have mentioned, newer versions are also supported longer so any vulnerabilities may only get patched in the new version.

Comment: +1 for the point about lack of support of older versions

Answer (score 0):

Generally, new release tend to be fast and safer. This makes browsing more fun and easier.